# How to access buttons and links within the content of a ag-grid cells using only the keyboard?

Tags: accessibility, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to make the interactive content of cells in ag-grid accessible to screen readers and keyboard only users.

Is there a configuration setting or technique in ag-grid that will allow keyboard only navigation to interact with buttons and links within the cells? The headers and filters allow CONTROL + RETURN keys to change the focus to their content but not the body cells.

I've created an example grid on Plnkr with columns that have both a link and a button. Any hints or suggestions would be awesome!

We're using ag-grid-community 25.1.0 and ag-grid-react 25.1.0.

https://plnkr.co/edit/8qDxw4GYnqdvjtAU

````
```
<div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
  <div
    id="myGrid"
    style={{
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
    }}
    className="ag-theme-alpine"
  >
    <AgGridReact
      modules={AllCommunityModules}
      frameworkComponents={{
        medalCellRenderer: MedalCellRenderer,
        totalValueRenderer: TotalValueRenderer,
        linkCellRenderer: LinkCellRenderer,
      }}
      defaultColDef={{
        editable: false,
        sortable: true,
        flex: 1,
        minWidth: 100,
        filter: true,
        resizable: true,
      }}
      onGridReady={onGridReady}
      rowData={rowData}
    >
      <AgGridColumn field="athlete" />
      <AgGridColumn field="year" cellRenderer="linkCellRenderer" />
      <AgGridColumn field="gold" cellRenderer="medalCellRenderer" />
      <AgGridColumn field="silver" cellRenderer="medalCellRenderer" />
      <AgGridColumn field="bronze" cellRenderer="medalCellRenderer" />
      <AgGridColumn
        field="total"
        minWidth={175}
        cellRenderer="totalValueRenderer"
      />
    </AgGridReact>
  </div>
</div>
```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using custom cell renderers and tapping into it's refresh lifecycle method as well as the grid's onCellFocus callback.

https://codesandbox.io/s/focus-links-7b6yz